# x axes in plot bar visualization in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, data-visualization, bar-chart

i have df.
[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoNDo.png)

I want add in my visualization 'Sub-Category' in x axes.
How i can do that?
Code:

```
df_neg_val.plot(kind='bar',x = 'Year',y='Profit')
```

[plot bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXTkK.png)

If i pointing two args in x = '' - i have error.
I'm read documentation, but i'm bad know english :(
Thanks for you reply :)

Comment: Can you sketch what you want the plot to look like, as it's not clear what you want as output. Something like [the second example in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html)?

Comment: i want add 'Sub-Category' on x axes , in order to see profit by years and subcategories

Comment: Can you sketch it, or find an image that looks like it, as this still isn't clear. Do you want [multiple bars](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/_images/pandas-DataFrame-plot-bar-2.png) for each year that represent each sub-category? Do you want a [stacked bar chart](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/_images/pandas-DataFrame-plot-bar-3.png) where each bar segment is a subcategory?

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2Trk.png)

Comment: "Do you want multiple bars for each year that represent each sub-category" - yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [`.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) your DataFrame so that `Year` becomes the index and `SubCategory` the columns, then plot it.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
   "Year": [2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002],
   "Pet": ["Dog", "Cat", "Dog", "Cat", "Dog", "Cat"],
   "Weight": [10, 5, 11, 6, 10, 6]})
df.pivot(index="Year", columns="Pet", values="Weight").plot.bar()
```

[image: Bar plot example]

As an aside, I don't love bar plots with years along the x-axis, as I don't consider years to be a categorical variable.